# Authorization, authentication when doing AJAX (jquery) calls to .net web services (asmx, wcf, etc), what do I need to know?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, authentication, authorization

I am prototyping a AJAX based web application running up against ASP.NET, where I need to have general authorization to different parts of the site, and also have to make sure that various web methods/web services can't be called by unauthorized users (from a rouge html page for example).

Is there anything I need to be aware of, or do things just work as if I was doing regular ASP.NET?

A set of best practices or things to look out for would be fantastic.

A side question, what do I gain by using WCF compared to ASMX?

Regards, Egil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works basically the same way as with regular ASP.NET and ASMX/WCF. The big difference is that you'll need to use the Membership API from the client-side (whioh is fully supported by ASP.NET AJAX).

Check out these resources:

[endpoint.tv - Securing RESTful services with ASP.NET Membership](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/endpointtv-Securing-RESTful-services-with-ASPNET-Membership/)

[How Do I: Use the ASP.NET AJAX Profile Services?](http://www.asp.net/learn/ajax-videos/video-166.aspx)